# limit of a trigonometric function, can i simplify further?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

evaluating lim x->0 (sin^2 x)/(1−cos⁡(x))

is it fair to re-write as:

(1−cos⁡(2x)/2)/(1−cos⁡(x))

and does this simplify any further? like to 2-cos(4x)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x = (1+\cos x)(1-\cos x).$$